# How to speed up Unocov converter in python>

Tags: python, flask, asynchronous

I am trying to convert a .docx file to pdf in python. However, I am faced with slow conversion speeds. The larger the pdf, it takes longer to open and convert. I tested on ubuntu, it took around 12 seconds to convert a 1mb, 12 page document, which is way too long.

I'm using Flask to run this.

```
async def convert_to_pdf(input_docx, output_pdf):
    try:
        unoconv_command = f'unoconvert "{input_docx}" "{output_pdf}"'
        proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(unoconv_command)
        await proc.communicate()
        print(f"Conversion successful: {input_docx} -> {output_pdf}")
    except asyncio.SubprocessError as e:
        error_msg = f"Error during conversion: {e}"
        print(error_msg)
```

I'm trying asyncio to run it, but that doesn't improve the time much. Is there a way I can adjust it to read the file faster?

Comment: Are you running `unoconv` in [server mode](https://github.com/unoconv/unoserver/) ?

Comment: Yes I am @pjcunningham, it's actually unoserver, the updated one